# Retrieve multiple data in Real-time - Firebase Web

Tags: web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var rootRef=firebase.database().ref().child("users");
   rootRef.on("child_added",snap=>{
      var name=snap.child("Name").val();
      var email=snap.child("Email").val();

      $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+email+ "</td><td><button class='remove_btn'>Remove</button></td></tr>");
   });
});
```

I used `child_added` event which retrieves the child data of users, but it does not update the data in real-time when I update the data in Firebase. `user_update` event does that thing, but I don't know how to use both of these events to solve the problem.

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve multiple data in real-time from Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is save your records as follows:

```
var rootRef=firebase.database().ref("users"))
rootRef.child(moment().utcOffset(0).unix()).set({
    Name: name,
    email: email
})
```

and to listen

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var rootRef=firebase.database().ref().child("users");
    rootRef.limitToLast(1).on("child_added",snap=>{
      var name=snap.child("Name").val();
      var email=snap.child("Email").val();
  });
});
```

in this case I use moment, but you can use the timestamp date

https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment